# Validate space in URL using regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using below code to validate URL. it is also validate space in URL. for e.g
`'http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/lookout/texas -tornadoes-granbury-photos-video-121304415.html'`

```
var post_permalink = 'http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/lookout/texas -tornadoes-granbury-photos-video-121304415.html';
if(/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test(post_permalink)){
      console.log('valid');
} else {
console.log('invalid');
}
```

Can any one suggest me where i need to do changes so that it will not take space in URL.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt3eq/1/)

thanks in advance

Comment: your querystring is'nt really a querystring ?

Comment: yes. i have taken for example. but we can check spaces by above querystring.

Comment: @adeneo : i have change query string now. if any case space in between `texas` and `-tornadoes` occure that case i need to validate

Comment: Just add `\s+` to the regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex can be simplified without changing its meaning.

This part:

```
(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.)
```

can be rewritten as:

```
(https?:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.)
```

This part:

```
[\-\.]{1}
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
[-.]
```

The capturing groups are not used, so you can make them non-capturing:

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/.*)?$/
```

The space problem can be fixed by changing `.*` at the end in `(?:\/.*)?` to `\S*` (the rest of the pattern doesn't allow space anyway):

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/
```